# Конкатенация php

Tags: php

Как правильно вот эту строку в php перевести?

```
sha1("from="+161+";to="+156+";"+dsqwdeqw564564qwe)
```

Comment: @RattleSneyk, скажу по секрету, что если вбить название вашей темы в гугл, то первая же ссылка будет ответом на вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sha1("from=".'161'.";to=".'156'.";".'dsqwdeqw564564qwe')
```